# android how to make view object with implement runnable open three diffrent time

Tags: android, multithreading

Hello I'm trying to make view object I have in my app to run three times and i can find how to do it or if it possible or not. any help will be appreciated.

I tried to do it this way but its not working

my thread object:

```
public class SlotMachineSlot extends View implements Runnable {

veriable...

public SlotMachineSlot(Context context, int x, int y, Bitmap SOURCE_BITMAP) {
    super(context);
    constructor...

}

public void spin(int newPlace) {
    class methoud
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    draw the objact
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        if (spinning) {
              thread function.
            }
}
```

the code i use to start the threads

```
public Thread[] thread = new Thread[3];

for (int i=0;i<3;i++){
        slots[i] = new SlotMachinSlot();
        thread[i] = new Thread(slots[i]);
        thread[i].start();
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you're trying to animate a `View` why aren't you using an `ObjectAnimator` and an `AnimatorSet`?

Answer (score 0):

sorry I didn't had a full understanding of what is a thread and how to use it the way I wanted to use it is bad and shouldn't be done and may cause problem.